# What is this plant growing along wires below the ceiling?

Tags: identification

I recently went to a restaurant in Bremen, Germany, and they had this plant growing along wires below the ceiling:

[image: Plant growing below the ceiling]

When I asked the waitstaff what kind of plant it was, they didn't know. But the owner gave me this:

[image]

My best guess after some web search is that it might be an *Epipremnum aureum*. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, agree, it looks like Epripremnum aureum. If you leave those cuttings in the bottle for a while, keep  the water topped up, they should form roots, then you can pot them up in new potting soil. In fact, looking at the picture, I'm not sure they haven't already formed rather long roots...